# Firefox print page - white font colors overidden to darker colors

Tags: html, css, firefox

I'm creating reports in html and would like users to be able to download them as PDF via the browsers native print functionality. ie ctrl + P or cmd + p

I've discovered an issue when print in Firefox, the browser seems to not allow printing in a white font color.

**The expected behaviour:**

let's say I have a basic div with purple background color and white text. I would expect the browser to render that element exactly like that and also print the page to pdf exactly like that.

**Actual behaviour:**

In Firefox only, the browser changes any font which is deemed too light to black. This could be a font colour which is white or any colour that is close to white ie a light grey.

Is there a way with CSS or other that I can force it to print to PDF any white font colors exactly white?

Worth noting: I had a similar issue with Firefox not rendering background colours on elements, I got around that by using the following CSS rules on the element that didn't have the background color rendering, this however doesn't seem to fix the light font color issue:

```
-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
color-adjust: exact;
```

I have also included some code to be able to replicate this issue:

```
<html>
  </head>
    <body>
      <section class="purple">
        <div class="page">
          <div class="oval single">day-to-day</div>
        </div>
      </section>

      <style>
        .oval {
          position: absolute;
          width: 300px;
          height: 60px;
          top: 45px;
          right: -50px;
          border-radius: 50%;
          color: #ffffff!important;
          text-align: left;
          line-height: 24px;
          opacity: 0.4;
          padding: 15px 15px 15px 50px;
        }

        .oval span {
          color: #ffffff!important;
        }

        .oval.sub{
            top: 108px;
        }

        .oval.single{
            top: 80px;
        }

        .page {
            font-size:24px;
            line-height: 34px;
            position: relative;
            width:1160px;
            height:1671px;
            padding:100px;
            page-break-after: always;
            color:#595959;
        }

        *, body {
            -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;
            font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', 'Arial', sans-serif;
        }

        .purple .oval {
            background-color: #3c0c5b;
            -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
            color-adjust: exact;
        }
      </style>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you save this to an html file and try printing the page via ctrl + p or cmd + p you will see it renders as it should in the browser as html but not in the PDF.

Comment: { Ctrl + P } then open Properties for that printer. Then locate the Color / Grayscale toggle in the Print driver software.

Comment: Is there a way around this without having the user manually change their settings for print?

Comment: Maybe this link could help you https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1114423

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One workaround is to set the text to transparent and then set text-shadow to the desired print color.
I had success in Firefox 70.0.1 using this solution.

```
<style>
    .oval {
      position: absolute;
      width: 300px;
      height: 60px;
      top: 45px;
      right: -50px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      color: transparent;
      text-shadow: 0 0 0px #fff;
      text-align: left;
      line-height: 24px;
      opacity: 0.4;
      padding: 15px 15px 15px 50px;
    }
...
</style>
```

https://codepen.io/joshmatt/pen/jOOzrEv